# Dutching Calculation

Tags: excel, calculation

I already have a dutching calculator to determine bet sizes, but am trying to automate the results process so if I type in either Win or Lost, the result appears. I think I have the elements correct, but I'm just not getting the exact syntax right.

You take a set of odds for each runner and turn that into a % expressed as a decimal. I will only ever have 2 runners and the overall stake between the 2 runners is always 100. The result for either winning is exactly the same, so only need half the formula for that calculation. This is the dutching formula:

```
=((1/H1) / (1/HI+1/J1))*100
```

The above code basically gives me the stake or this runner

For the automated result, I tried this, but failed to get a result:

```
=IF(K1="LOST"),-100,(((1/H1) / (1/H1+1/J1)*100)*H1)-100
```

This is using the word Lost as the key, but could be reversed to use Win, but then the calculation would be earlier.

It should be basically saying, if K1 says LOST, -100 (loss of stake), if not, then use the dutching calculation `(1/H1) / (1/H1+1/J1)*100)` and multiply that by the odds (H1) and deduct the full stake of 100.

The dutching formula works on its own to determine the stake. If the result is anything other than Lost, the dutching stake should be multiplied by the odds in H1 and the stake of 100 deducted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what dutching is, but to put your formula into a syntax that works, you've put the closing parenthesis after your first argument. The following should work as a formula but I don't know if the calculation will be correct:

```
=IF(K1="LOST",-100,(((1/H1) / (1/H1+1/J1)*100)*H1)-100)
```

Comment: Also, do you need to enclose `H1 + 1`? This is calculating `(1/H1) + (1/J1)`

Comment: That works a treat. Dutching is simply using mathematics to determine your staking in a horse race. I choose 2 runners and the original formula tells me how much to place on each based on their odds. If either runners comes in, the collect is exactly the same.

Regardless, the formula works perfect. Thanks a bunch